# How to reference a resources file for dimensions in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Coming from Android development, it's incredibly useful (and expected) to be able to have hardcoded values, such as colors, dimensions and sizes in xml files, and reference those files in the UI code, see (pseudo code) example:

`dimensions.xml`:

```
<item name="title_textsize">24</item>
```

`login_screen.xml`:

```
<TextView
    text_size=@dimensions/title_textsize />
```

This way, it's easy to make changes while your application grows, and in this case, not having to go through every single UI file in your project and find every title, and change their text size.

---

**Question:** Is there a way on Xcode to reference resource files in Storyboard?

**Edit:** To see the storyboard's code, we can right click it and select "Open as Source Code", but how do we reference a resources file to avoid duplicating values in that code?

Comment: Hi! Same question here. Did you find solution?

Comment: @VitaliyA yeah using flutter

Comment: That is not a solution. You just used totally different framework that has nothing to do with XCode. Your question specifically asks for solution in XCode storyboard

Answer (score -2):

To open Storyboard as XMl source:

Right click on your storyboard, you will see a menu, hover over "Open As" then select "Source Code"

To go back to view storyboard in the design build mode,

Right click on your storyboard, you will see a menu, hover over "Open As" then select "Interface Builder -- Storyboard"

Comment: You did not read the question, did you?